# How do I count project ids based on occurrence in two different tables in SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to get a count of fv_id in table B depending on the occurrence of user_id in both tables A and B.

The conditions may sound a bit complex, but in summary:

1. I want to count fv_id if the user_id is the first ever occurrence in both tables A and B for a particular month. That is the user_id should not have occurred in the prior month.
2. I also want to count fv_id in table B if the date of occurence of the user_id in table B is before the date of occurence in table A.
3. Don't count fv_id in table B for a given month, if user_id has occurred in prior month in either table A or table B.

The fv_ids can be different in both tables for the same user_id.

I have tried a bunch of "where not exists" but it is not working as intended.

My next thinking is to create a log of all user_ids from both tables A and B and go from there, but I have not yet achieved it.

Any insights or help is super appreciated.

**Table A:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `project.dataset.tableA` (
  `month` STRING,
  `fv_id` INT64,
  `user_id` INT64
);

INSERT INTO `project.dataset.tableA` (`month`, `fv_id`, `user_id`) VALUES
('1/01/2021', 96, 1066),
('1/01/2021', 340, 1097),
('1/01/2021', 487, 1232),
('1/01/2021', 426, 1022),
('1/01/2021', 195, 1468),
('1/01/2021', 369, 1108),
('1/02/2021', 321, 1358),
('1/02/2021', 346, 1190),
('1/02/2021', 97, 1136),
('1/02/2021', 466, 1154),
('1/02/2021', 164, 1143),
('1/03/2021', 379, 1243),
('1/03/2021', 77, 1239),
('1/03/2021', 199, 1014),
('1/03/2021', 33, 1066),
('1/03/2021', 87, 1250),
('1/03/2021', 409, 1015),
('1/03/2021', 178, 1439),
('1/03/2021', 82, 1327),
('1/03/2021', 404, 1003),
('1/03/2021', 88, 1150),
('1/03/2021', 10, 1007),
('1/04/2021', 92, 8000);
```

**Table B:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `project.dataset.tableB` (
  `month` STRING,
  `fv_id` INT64,
  `user_id` INT64
);

INSERT INTO `project.dataset.tableB` (`month`, `fv_id`, `user_id`) VALUES
('1/01/2021', 525, 1066),
('1/01/2021', 589, 1468),
('1/01/2021', 643, 1108),
('1/01/2021', 585, 8000),
('1/02/2021', 578, 1066),
('1/02/2021', 504, 6879),
('1/02/2021', 637, 1143),
('1/03/2021', 621, 1327),
('1/03/2021', 519, 1097),
('1/03/2021', 648, 8000),
('1/03/2021', 611, 1358),
('1/04/2021', 788, 4878);
```

**Result required:**

| entry_month | count of fv_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1/01/2021 | 4 |
| 1/02/2021 | 2 |
| 1/03/2021 | 1 |
| 1/04/2021 | 1 |

Comment: Can you provide the DDL (CREATE TABLE)  and DML (INSERT ) statements to show the sample data you wish you have processed rather than the screenshots?

Comment: I have added in sqlfiddle friendly code. I am not really good at creating these tables. But it did work in sqlfiddle.